# Redshift Query Ignoring LIMIT Clause

Tags: amazon-redshift

While investigating duplicate event_id's, we noticed that Redshift seems to be ignoring the LIMIT clause on a simple query:

```
SELECT se_action
FROM events
WHERE event_id = 'e4a5ffbe-6a1d-47b7-ac10-6c57b2cd65ed'
ORDER BY collector_tstamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

When running this query, I receive over 800 results. Interestingly, if I remove the `ORDER BY` clause, I receive only one result as intended.

How do I get this to properly output a single result, or does this sound like a bug with Redshift?

Comment: Interestingly, if you run an `EXPLAIN` on that, the XN Limit isn't in the plan, where it is with other queries.

Comment: They way you have your sql set up it should work but you could always test it by changing the amount limited and by trying to add an 'OFFSET' and see if it works. Strange it didn't show up with the 'EXPLAIN'

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways I can think of that will limit the amount of results you get from a quarry and they are `LIMIT` and `TOP`

Try this `TOP` Example

```
SELECT TOP 1 se_action
FROM events
WHERE event_id = 'e4a5ffbe-6a1d-47b7-ac10-6c57b2cd65ed'
ORDER BY collector_tstamp DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This does sound like a bug in Redshift. If you use `LIMIT 1` (or `TOP 1`) then the query should return only one row.

If you are subscribed to AWS Support, please open an issue so that they can trace the underlying problem. If you are not subscribed to support, you can post to the [Amazon Redshift discussion forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=155).

Answer (score 0):

Lately reply here but i faced this issue too and noted an pattern:

Like your query, mine is using too a DistKey UUID in WHERE clause comparing string with "=" operator, in this cenario i'm facing same problem with bellow ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses being totally discard from the query (even from explain).

But when i just change the operator "=" per "LIKE" in WHERE clause my query works fine

Ex:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'UUID' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
Doesn't work, filter by "where" but discard "order by" and "limit"

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE 'UUID' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
Works perfectly with "order by" and "limit"

I didn't find anything related to this in forums but seems like a redshift bug, do you filled a bug report on AWS?

Comment: If you have AQUA enabled (and it's enabled by default), your LIKE will be going to AQUA, which is a completely different query processing engine.